# What is the proper procedure to replace an existing paid certificate with lets encrypt

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, lets-encrypt

I have a paid certificate that's about to expire soon.

I would like to use lets encrypt cert in replacement of this one.

What is the appropriate procedure to do this?

Info:
- CentOS 6.3
- Apache 2.2
- Digicert
- Still don't have any lets encrypt stuff installed

Comment: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centos6-apache.html - This is one out of many relevant links I could find by entering "letsencrypt apache centos" in a search engine. Certbot is the most used client but you can find [dozens of alternatives on the letsencrypt site](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/). As a start, you can have a look at [how letsencrypt works](https://letsencrypt.org/how-it-works/)

Comment: Be careful if you have HPKP activated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visiting the Let's encrypt webpage helps a lot.
https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/

If you do have shell access to your server all you have to do is follow the instructions in the link bellow. You can specify OS and Server type as you can see in the URL.

https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centos6-apache

Comment: ok, looks like there is no such thing. Will take a look there then. TY